# Incorrect response json coding and array violation Woocomerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I get the answer in the wrong encoding. Perhaps because of this, the array construction does not work. How to fix it?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.example.com/api/index.php?get_status");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$decoded = (array) json_decode($result);

// Update order status
if( isset($decoded['result']) && $decoded['result'] == 'success' && isset($decoded['status']) && ! empty($decoded['status']) ){
    if( $decoded['status'] == "Order Completed" )
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    elseif( $decoded['status'] == "Order Cancelled" )
        $order->update_status( 'cancelled' );
}
```

I looked for solutions and tried it, but it does not work either:

```
$decoded = (array) json_decode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

`print_r( $decoded );` show:

```
Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )
```

`print_r ( $result );` show:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.2.1 Date: Thu, 05 Jul 2018 18:59:07 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2 Vary: Accept-Encoding Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; {"result":"success","status":"\u0412\u044b\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u043d"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking to receive header info in the server response. You can't decode this with `json_decode()`.

To get a pure JSON-only response from the server, you need to set:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

Once you get the valid JSON in your response, you can turn it into a PHP array as follows(set the second arg to true): `$decoded = json_decode($result, true);`

Now `$decoded` is a PHP associative array that you can traverse.

Comment: Thank you! For me, the removal of the line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);` helped.